For loop not writing images
I'm attempting to write a for loop that opens each image in a folder, processes it, and then outputs it back into the same folder. The problem is, when I run the script, nothing happens. I just see the script displayed in the command window. I have tried running each part of the script outside of the loop, and the individual parts seem to be okay. There are no errors when this happens. For reference, I have defined the guassian noise image outside of the loop, with the loop adding the guassian noise over the original image. I then want to append a number to the end of the new image name, so the original image is not deleted.
import os
import glob
import cv2
import numpy as np
img_dir = "path to folder"
data_path = os.path.join(img_dir, '*tif')
files = glob.glob(data_path)
data = []
#Loop
i = 0
for f1 in files:
    img = cv2.imread(f1)
    data.append(img)
    #image processing
    cv2.imwrite(
        "{}{}_{:07d}.tif".format(
            img_dir,
            f1.split("/")[-1].strip(".tif"),
            i),
        img)        
    i += 1


Your indentation inside the loop is not consistent. Fix it.

Whoops, good catch! Fixed it- the code came out pasted a little funky on browser. Still the same story when running the code though, as the indents were fine

If I may ask...why are you using five spaces? The standard is four AFAIK.

I know, the format was a little strange when I pasted it in the broswer, so I just spaced the rest to match up. :) Fixed it for clarity!

Are you sure the output filename is correct? You really ought to use os.path for path manipulation instead of parsing/cobbling them together by hand. | Proper [mcve] is still missing.

@Elerium115 as stated above, I have defined guass_noise outside the for loop.

Add print statements to the script to see what it's doing when you run it.

Aside: Use for i, f1 in enumerate(files): instead of incrementing i yourself.

Code is not testable without definition of guess_noise and your imports

[mre] required. debugging required.

Edited for a reproducible example! Sorry all- I'm used to posting in R and forgot about the imports being essential to the reproducibility aspect. Also didn't think that the guassian image definition would be important- thank you all for pointing that out. Hopefully things are easier to follow now!

Debugging details are still missing. Is there anything in the files variable? Does anything happen in the for-loop? What if you put a print statement inside?

I got it figured out for anyone with similar problems. This was a path issue. I was pulling from a list and python didn't like that. The following changes (specifically the definition of "files" and the for loop definition are what worked.
import os
import glob
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Set working directory
wrking_dir = os.chdir(os.path.join(path))

#Get images from working directory
files = glob.glob("*.tif")

#Create zero image with same dimensions as input image
gauss_noise=np.zeros((400,400, 3),dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.randn(gauss_noise,5,95)
gauss_noise=(gauss_noise*10.5).astype(np.uint8)

#Loop over images to add guassian mask and then save
i = 0
for file in files:
    img=cv2.imread(file)
    #Add gaussian noise image to OG image
    gn_img=cv2.add(img,gauss_noise)
    #cv2.imwrite("{}{}_{:02d}.tif".format(img_dir,file.split("/")[-1].strip(".tif"), i), gn_img)        
    cv2.imwrite('masked_' + file, gn_img) 

